# Read Spring properties in React

Tags: spring, maven, reactjs, properties

I have a Spring/React webapp. In my application.properties file I defined `spring.data.rest.base-path = /api`so when running the app locally, everything is accessible on `localhost:8080/api`. If I deploy this to my tomcat, the all the stuff goes to `localhost:8080/warname/api`.
I can easily define my warname in my properties file. And in React,

```
path: '/api/myStuff'
```

I can access my data.
Also I can change that to

```
path: '/warname/api/myStuff'
```

and everything will work. But to make things easier, it would be better to read the warname from my pom.xml so I wouldn't have to change every path in my .js. How to get that done?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a directory named `ROOT` in your Tomcat directory, you have to remove it and change the name of your war to `ROOT.war` so that when Tomcat explodes the war it will be the main root project.

Comment: I don't want it to be in the main root.

Comment: in order for you to achieve what it is you're after you have to rename your war to root so that it becomes the root project in your tomcat install. Than you can have `/api/myStuff` without having `/warname/api/myStuff`